# Dropbox icon is not working Xubuntu, UbuntuStudio 17.04

Tags: xubuntu, icons, dropbox, ubuntu-studio

Icon not working in Xubuntu, UbuntuStudio 17.04

[image: dropbox not working]

Comment: @KevinBowen why? Yes, the OP is linking to their blog, but they also took the trouble to reproduce the blog's content here, so the question and answer can stand on their own even if the linked information disappears. There's nothing wrong with that, on the contrary.

Comment: Hi Kevin Bowen and terdon, I delete my blog link that I set at the end of my answer (sorry my english, I am spanish parlant). The reason for I put that link is because I need to mantain a copy of my entry for my, and if someone find that entry in my blog I want not think that I copy and paste here.

Comment: @KevinBowen if you feel something is a "lousy answer", then downvote and move on and save your attitude for others. If your comment can't say anything constructive, it is just noise and uncalled for.

Answer (score 2):

Do a standard dropbox install.
Edit your panel preferences, find and remove the Unity indicator item. Withthis item not present, Dropbox won't try to use it.

log out and log in.
The icon will work.

However, this means you lose the Unity indicator panel. I personally don't miss it.

If you want this, you can add it back. log out and log in, and the broken Dropbox icon will be back.

Next, verify if this solution works for you

from a terminal:

`dropbox stop` # the icon disappears

`dbus-launch dropbox start -i` #for me, this gives a working dropbox icon despite the indicator panel

if that works, you need to disable the Dropbox-installed start up item and add your own (system preferences -> Session and Startup) to start it with the dbus-launch method.

I verified this in a new Xubuntu 17.10 install.

Answer (score -1):

**RESUME:**

- This are the easy way
- With this method you don't lose panel indicators
- This method working for Ubuntu 17.04 flavors

**1.- MAKE THE LAUNCHER SCRIPT**

[image: 01 dropbox solve icon Ubuntu 17.04]

First you need to install Gedit if you do not have it installed:

```
sudo apt-get install gedit
```

Create an script, in the terminal:

```
gedit scriptdropbox
```

copy next code inside:

```
#! /bin/bash
dbus-launch ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd &
```

Save it. Now set executable:

```
chmod 755 scriptdropbox
```

**2.- EDIT DROPBOX.DESKTOP ON SYSTEM APPLICATIONS**

[image: 02 dropbox solve icon Ubuntu 17.04]

Now make a backup of dropbox.desktop:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop /usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop.back
```

and edit in the terminal:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop
```

Change this:

Exec=dropbox start -i

for this:

Exec=/home/yourusername/scriptdropbox

Save it.

**3.- EDIT DROPBOX.DESKTOP IN AUTOSTART APPS**

[image: 03 dropbox solve icon Ubuntu 17.04]

Next put in the terminal:

```
gedit ~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop
```

Change this:

Exec=dropbox start -i

for this:

Exec=/home/yourusername/scriptdropbox

Save it.

Restart

working

[image: working dropbox]

This tutorial is a fork from:
linux - Dropbox system tray icon missing, not working - Super User
https://superuser.com/questions/1037769/dropbox-system-tray-icon-missing-not-working